Is there anyway to include subtitles or just plain text in composite mode?
Just a general question, all the stuff I've found include making text objects and including them in the scene which is an overkill I think.
I find it so hard to believe blender can do all this stuff in composite stage but can not just add simple text to an already rendered image?
Am I wrong on this?  I found this before and it seems like an overkill.
Overlay Text to an image in the Compositor

The video sequence editor has a text layer you can add. I don't know if it's pre or post composite step but that's probably easier than using actual text objects.
